# Upload a plain text caption to Youtube

Tags: caption, youtube-data-api

I need to upload plain text file ('*.txt' with 'utf-8' encoding) to youtube via api-v3 and then I plan to auto-sync this caption to get subtitles format from plain text.
Uploading completes with failureReason is unknownFormat and status of caption is 'Track content is not processed.' on web-page
How should I upload plain-text as caption to Auto-sync via api-v3?

Comment: I upload plain text to Auto-sync through browser now for my purposes.

Comment: I have same problem :( Have you find solution?

Comment: I figured out that youtube has no api for that. So I used selenium web driver to upload plain text to youtube video as a caption

Comment: Sounds interesting! Could you please provide example?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Crazymax11/6ed3c5cbbc69280efdc6 part of my python script that uploads subtitles in sub.txt as a caption of videoid video in youtube. You need to login as owner of video.  Try it, I used it for some time, but later we decided use another tech for project purposes